# How do I profile a Xamarin.Mac app built with Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: mono, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to profile a Xamarin.Mac app with the mono profiler, but I encounter errors. The app is built locally for debugging with Visual Studio for Mac and built for the App Store using the MSBuild CLI.

I tried this:

1. Build the app through Visual Studio for Mac, with Full debug information
2. `mono --profile=log "MyApp.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MyApp.exe"`

which failed with

stdout:

```
aot-runtime.c:2441: Image out of date assembly:/Users/chase/MyApp/MyAppWeb/projects/MyApp.Mac/bin/Debug/MyApp (Dev).app/Contents/MonoBundle/MyApp (Dev).exe.dylib type:<unknown type> member:(null) signature:<none>
```

stderr:

```
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

    0   mono                                0x000000010578ebf8 mono_handle_native_crash + 264
    1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff5fa03f5a _sigtramp + 26
    2   mono                                0x0000000105abb148 pvars + 328
    3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff5f7a11ae abort + 127
    4   mono                                0x000000010599cb0f mono_log_write_logfile + 351
    5   mono                                0x00000001059b551e monoeg_g_log + 206
    6   mono                                0x00000001059a2cc6 mono_error_assert_ok_pos + 54
    7   mono                                0x000000010577512f decode_cached_class_info + 447
    8   mono                                0x0000000105775530 mono_aot_get_cached_class_info + 432
    9   mono                                0x0000000105856d5c mono_class_init + 364
    10  mono                                0x0000000105700f38 mono_method_to_ir + 86040
    11  mono                                0x00000001056d8807 mini_method_compile + 3287
    12  mono                                0x00000001056dbf16 mono_jit_compile_method_inner + 790
    13  mono                                0x00000001056df4d2 mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt + 1442
    14  mono                                0x00000001056e2f25 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 501
    15  mono                                0x00000001058dbab4 do_runtime_invoke + 84
    16  mono                                0x00000001058df079 do_exec_main_checked + 137
    17  mono                                0x0000000105750b0f mono_jit_exec + 287
    18  mono                                0x0000000105753a8d mono_main + 11069
    19  mono                                0x00000001056d2c4d main + 253
    20  mono                                0x00000001056d2b44 start + 52

Debug info from gdb:

(lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.MwIxeR'
Executing commands in '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.MwIxeR'.
(lldb) process attach --pid 3702
warning: (x86_64) /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.10.1/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.dylib empty dSYM file detected, dSYM was created with an executable with no debug info.
Process 3702 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'tid_307', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5f846232 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4:
->  0x7fff5f846232 <+10>: jae    0x7fff5f84623c            ; <+20>
    0x7fff5f846234 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff5f846237 <+15>: jmp    0x7fff5f83cb25            ; cerror
    0x7fff5f84623c <+20>: retq   
Target 0: (mono) stopped.

Executable module set to "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono".
Architecture set to: x86_64h-apple-macosx.
(lldb) thread list
Process 3702 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1e6e4, 0x00007fff5f846232 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, name = 'tid_307', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  thread #2: tid = 0x1e6e7, 0x00007fff5f845a1e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10, name = 'SGen worker'
  thread #3: tid = 0x1e6e8, 0x00007fff5f83c246 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'Finalizer'
  thread #4: tid = 0x1e6e9, 0x00007fff5f83c246 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'Profiler sampler'
  thread #5: tid = 0x1e6ea, 0x00007fff5f845cfa libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10, name = 'Profiler helper'
  thread #6: tid = 0x1e6eb, 0x00007fff5f83c246 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'Profiler writer'
  thread #7: tid = 0x1e6ec, 0x00007fff5f83c25e libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10, name = 'Profiler dumper'
(lldb) thread backtrace all
* thread #1, name = 'tid_307', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff5f846232 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10
    frame #1: 0x000000010578ec9f mono`mono_handle_native_crash(signal=<unavailable>, ctx=<unavailable>, info=<unavailable>) at mini-exceptions.c:2830 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x00007fff5fa03f5a libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 26
    frame #3: 0x00007fff5f845b6f libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 11
    frame #4: 0x00007fff5fa10080 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 333
    frame #5: 0x00007fff5f7a11ae libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #6: 0x000000010599cb0f mono`mono_log_write_logfile(log_domain=<unavailable>, level=<unavailable>, hdr=<unavailable>, message="aot-runtime.c:2441: Image out of date assembly:/Users/chase/MyApp/MyAppWeb/projects/MyApp.Mac/bin/Debug/MyApp (Dev).app/Contents/MonoBundle/MyApp (Dev).exe.dylib type:<unknown type> member:(null) signature:<none>\n") at mono-log-common.c:135 [opt]
    frame #7: 0x00000001059b551e mono`monoeg_g_log [inlined] monoeg_g_logv at goutput.c:115 [opt]
    frame #8: 0x00000001059b54d8 mono`monoeg_g_log(log_domain=0x0000000000000000, log_level=G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, format=<unavailable>) at goutput.c:125 [opt]
    frame #9: 0x00000001059a2cc6 mono`mono_error_assert_ok_pos(error=<unavailable>, filename="aot-runtime.c", lineno=2441) at mono-error.c:171 [opt]
    frame #10: 0x000000010577512f mono`decode_cached_class_info(module=<unavailable>, info=<unavailable>, buf=" \x10À(\x12", endbuf=0x00007ffeea52ed68) at aot-runtime.c:2441 [opt]
    frame #11: 0x0000000105775530 mono`mono_aot_get_cached_class_info(klass=<unavailable>, res=<unavailable>) at aot-runtime.c:2515 [opt]
    frame #12: 0x0000000105856d5c mono`mono_class_init [inlined] mono_class_get_cached_class_info(klass=0x00007fba84e0c1c8, res=<unavailable>) at class.c:8958 [opt]
    frame #13: 0x0000000105856d44 mono`mono_class_init(klass=0x00007fba84e0c1c8) at class.c:4975 [opt]
    frame #14: 0x0000000105700f38 mono`mono_method_to_ir(cfg=<unavailable>, method=<unavailable>, start_bblock=0x00007fba8681f430, end_bblock=0x00007fba8681f580, return_var=0x0000000000000000, inline_args=0x00007fba8681fe28, inline_offset=<unavailable>, is_virtual_call=<unavailable>) at method-to-ir.c:8404 [opt]
    frame #15: 0x00000001056d8807 mono`mini_method_compile(method=<unavailable>, opts=370239999, domain=0x00007fba84c0a040, flags=JIT_FLAG_RUN_CCTORS, parts=0, aot_method_index=-1) at mini.c:3440 [opt]
    frame #16: 0x00000001056dbf16 mono`mono_jit_compile_method_inner(method=0x00007fba84c0b928, target_domain=0x00007fba84c0a040, opt=370239999, error=0x00007ffeea52f688) at mini.c:4181 [opt]
    frame #17: 0x00000001056df4d2 mono`mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt(method=0x00007fba84c0b928, opt=<unavailable>, jit_only=<unavailable>, error=0x00007ffeea52f688) at mini-runtime.c:2129 [opt]
    frame #18: 0x00000001056e2f25 mono`mono_jit_runtime_invoke [inlined] mono_jit_compile_method(method=<unavailable>, error=0x00007ffeea52f688) at mini-runtime.c:2175 [opt]
    frame #19: 0x00000001056e2f01 mono`mono_jit_runtime_invoke(method=0x00007fba84c0b928, obj=<unavailable>, params=0x00007ffeea52f648, exc=0x0000000000000000, error=<unavailable>) at mini-runtime.c:2687 [opt]
    frame #20: 0x00000001058dbab4 mono`do_runtime_invoke(method=0x00007fba84c0b928, obj=0x0000000000000000, params=0x00007ffeea52f648, exc=0x0000000000000000, error=0x00007ffeea52f688) at object.c:2887 [opt]
    frame #21: 0x00000001058df079 mono`do_exec_main_checked [inlined] mono_runtime_invoke_checked(method=<unavailable>, obj=<unavailable>, error=<unavailable>) at object.c:3040 [opt]
    frame #22: 0x00000001058df038 mono`do_exec_main_checked(method=0x00007fba84c0b928, args=<unavailable>, error=0x00007ffeea52f688) at object.c:4784 [opt]
    frame #23: 0x0000000105750b0f mono`mono_jit_exec(domain=<unavailable>, assembly=<unavailable>, argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeea52fa18) at driver.g.c:1210 [opt]
    frame #24: 0x0000000105753a8d mono`mono_main [inlined] main_thread_handler at driver.g.c:1287 [opt]
    frame #25: 0x0000000105753a59 mono`mono_main(argc=<unavailable>, argv=<unavailable>) at driver.g.c:2417 [opt]
    frame #26: 0x00000001056d2c4d mono`main [inlined] mono_main_with_options(argc=<unavailable>, argv=<unavailable>) at main.c:47 [opt]
    frame #27: 0x00000001056d2c39 mono`main(argc=3, argv=<unavailable>) at main.c:340 [opt]
    frame #28: 0x00000001056d2b44 mono`start + 52
  thread #2, name = 'SGen worker'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5f845a1e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff5fa0e589 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 732
    frame #2: 0x0000000105993ffe mono`thread_func [inlined] mono_os_cond_wait(mutex=<unavailable>) at mono-os-mutex.h:173 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x0000000105993feb mono`thread_func at sgen-thread-pool.c:165 [opt]
    frame #4: 0x0000000105993fdd mono`thread_func(data=0x0000000000000000) at sgen-thread-pool.c:196 [opt]
    frame #5: 0x00007fff5fa0d661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #6: 0x00007fff5fa0d50d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #7: 0x00007fff5fa0cbf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #3, name = 'Finalizer'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5f83c246 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000105941a9c mono`finalizer_thread [inlined] mono_os_sem_wait(flags=MONO_SEM_FLAGS_ALERTABLE) at mono-os-semaphore.h:90 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x0000000105941a91 mono`finalizer_thread at mono-coop-semaphore.h:43 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x0000000105941a85 mono`finalizer_thread(unused=<unavailable>) at gc.c:852 [opt]
    frame #4: 0x00000001058fd960 mono`start_wrapper [inlined] start_wrapper_internal at threads.c:1004 [opt]
    frame #5: 0x00000001058fd8c3 mono`start_wrapper(data=<unavailable>) at threads.c:1064 [opt]
    frame #6: 0x00007fff5fa0d661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #7: 0x00007fff5fa0d50d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #8: 0x00007fff5fa0cbf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #4, name = 'Profiler sampler'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5f83c246 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001058eaf3b mono`mono_profiler_sampling_thread_wait [inlined] mono_os_sem_wait(flags=MONO_SEM_FLAGS_NONE) at mono-os-semaphore.h:90 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x00000001058eaf24 mono`mono_profiler_sampling_thread_wait at profiler.c:536 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x00000001058308c7 mono`sampling_thread_func(data=<unavailable>) at mini-posix.c:643 [opt]
    frame #4: 0x00007fff5fa0d661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #5: 0x00007fff5fa0d50d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #6: 0x00007fff5fa0cbf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #5, name = 'Profiler helper'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5f845cfa libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000105c08bde libmono-profiler-log.0.dylib`helper_thread(arg=<unavailable>) at log.c:3773 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x00007fff5fa0d661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #3: 0x00007fff5fa0d50d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #4: 0x00007fff5fa0cbf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #6, name = 'Profiler writer'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5f83c246 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000105c0987b libmono-profiler-log.0.dylib`writer_thread [inlined] mono_os_sem_wait at mono-os-semaphore.h:90 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x0000000105c09862 libmono-profiler-log.0.dylib`writer_thread(arg=<unavailable>) at log.c:4009 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x00007fff5fa0d661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #4: 0x00007fff5fa0d50d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #5: 0x00007fff5fa0cbf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
  thread #7, name = 'Profiler dumper'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5f83c25e libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000105c0a3d2 libmono-profiler-log.0.dylib`dumper_thread [inlined] mono_os_sem_timedwait(timeout_ms=1000, flags=MONO_SEM_FLAGS_NONE) at mono-os-semaphore.h:124 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x0000000105c0a3be libmono-profiler-log.0.dylib`dumper_thread(arg=<unavailable>) at log.c:4118 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x00007fff5fa0d661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #4: 0x00007fff5fa0d50d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #5: 0x00007fff5fa0cbf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
(lldb) detach

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Process 3702 detached
(lldb) quit
```

My mono version is

```
Mono JIT compiler version 5.10.1.57 (2017-12/ea8a24b1bbf Tue Apr 24 14:53:01 EDT 2018)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    Interpreter:   yes
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-master/8b1520c8aae)
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

How can I fix this issue? More generally, **how can I profile a Xamarin.Mac app bundle with the mono profiler?**

Related question: [Running Instruments on a Xamarin.Mac application bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988498/running-instruments-on-a-xamarin-mac-application-bundle), which asks about profiling with Instruments for Mac instead of with the mono profiler.

EDIT

## MONO_ENV_OPTIONS

I tried [Filip Navara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686047/1663774)

> Xamarin.Mac has a particular startup sequence and embeds a particular version of the Mono runtime with it. By running "mono" directly you bypass the startup sequence and it can cause problems. The proper way is to use the MONO_ENV_OPTIONS environment variable to pass the options: MONO_ENV_OPTIONS=--profile=log MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp.

but I get an error:

```
echo $MONO_ENV_OPTIONS
MONO_ENV_OPTIONS=--profile=log /Users/chase/MyApp/MyAppWeb/projects/MyApp.Mac/bin/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
cd /Users/chase/MyApp/MyAppWeb/projects/MyApp.Mac/bin/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/
./MyApp
Cannot open assembly '/Users/chase/MyApp/MyAppWeb/projects/MyApp.Mac/bin/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

If I clear MONO_ENV_OPTIONS, then I do not get the error, and the application runs correctly (but, of course, the profiler does not run).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will help with your particular error, but here's couple of hints.

Xamarin.Mac has a [particular startup sequence](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/78583313ebe50f98d7e801ee2b10328b646f4ade/runtime/launcher.m) and embeds a particular version of the Mono runtime with it. By running "mono" directly you bypass the startup sequence and it can cause problems. The proper way is to use the `MONO_ENV_OPTIONS` environment variable to pass the options: `MONO_ENV_OPTIONS=--profile=log MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`.

Alternative way to profile the application is to adapt the [MonoDevelop code](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/addins/PerformanceDiagnostics/PerformanceDiagnostics/UIThreadMonitor.cs#L75). It uses the system `sample` tool and then post-processes the output to translate opaque function offsets into .NET method names.

Comment: Filip, I got things to work by setting up custom run configurations in Visual Studio for Mac that set the MONO_ENV_OPTIONS environment variable. I probably just misunderstood how to properly invoke `mono` from a terminal. Assuming `mono` is on my path, `MONO_ENV_OPTIONS` is set, and `MyApp.app` is in the working directory, what exactly should I run from a terminal?